# how to get true css property names from CSSStyleDeclaration object?

Tags: javascript, css

The thing is that some css properties have different name is javascript, for example `textOverflow` in js is `text-overflow` in css.

Is there a translation table somewhere in js engine that I can access or I must do myself a translation array or object like:

```
transObj = { textOverflow : 'text-overflow' };
```

For example I'm looping through this object and all I get is only js names:

```
for (var n in csd) {
  if (!csd.hasOwnProperty(n)) continue;
  csd[n].getTrueCSSName() // is there something like this ?
}
```

Or maybe simple regex replace will be ok, but I don't know if rule that all big letters in js names tranlsate to `-[a-z]` in css names ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All css style which contain a `-` are replaced by their *camelCase* representation in ECMAscript, since we can't use `-` in all occasions. You can translate the names, by invoking a regular expression like this:

```
var name = "font-width";

// convert names like "font-width" into css camelCase form like "fontWidth"
name = name.replace( /-(\w)/g, function _replace( $1, $2 ) {
    return $2.toUpperCase();
});
```

which also works for like `-webkit-box-shadow` or whatnot.

Comment: and there are no exceptions ? Is this regex safe ? And the same is other way around from js to css ?

Comment: @rsk82: I'm not aware of any exceptions at least.

Comment: `float` translates to `cssFloat` :(