# how does it work element.style["background-color"]

Tags: javascript, html, css, object, properties

There is not property name in `element.style` object. But when we reach it by bracket notation it returns string value.

for example

```
Object.keys(document.body.style).includes("background-color") //false
```

but

```
document.body.style["background-color"] // returns ""
```

So how does this mechanism work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to get true css property names from CSSStyleDeclaration object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11799364/how-to-get-true-css-property-names-from-cssstyledeclaration-object)

Comment: @HarunYilmaz doesn't actually. I wonder that is there a special getter mechanism which work with any property name.

Comment: Hi. Maybe you want to have a look at this API documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration (I'm not sure which getter mechanism it uses, btw)

Comment: @HarunYilmaz I found this link "CSSStyleDeclaration named properties" in your MDN link but it doesn't give any explanation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is it Object.hasOwn(x,y) !== Reflect.ownKeys(x).includes(y) if x is a CSSStyleDeclaration object and y is a hyphenated property like 'z-index'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77668065/why-is-it-object-hasownx-y-reflect-ownkeysx-includesy-if-x-is-a-csssty)

Answer (score 0):

Since ECMAScript6,  you can use the Proxy mechanism to override the get operation.

Comment: I do not know that  style object use or not but Proxy mechanist can work in this situation. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

The difference is that `Object.keys` returns object's **own** properties. So `background-color` is an inherited property. You can see more on [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

Comment: inherited from where. I couldn't find it in inheritance chain

Comment: Just because `Object.keys` only shows own properties does not mean that `background-color` is inherited, and is not the case here.

Comment: If you try to `console.log` the style object, you see that the property is named `backgroundColor`. Hence I guess it uses a getter mechanism which converts the property name from kebab-case to camelCase and it's not about the inheritance.

Comment: @HarunYilmaz I agree with you but. Does it use Proxy?