# Why is it Object.hasOwn(x,y) !== Reflect.ownKeys(x).includes(y) if x is a CSSStyleDeclaration object and y is a hyphenated property like 'z-index'?

Tags: javascript, css

The following expressions both evaluate to true:

```
'z-index' in getComputedStyle(document.body) // true
Reflect.has(getComputedStyle(document.body), 'z-index')  // true
```

In fact, the following also evaluate to true, which suggests that 'z-index' is the name of an *own* property of the corresponding CSSStyleDeclaration object:

```
getComputedStyle(document.body).hasOwnProperty('z-index')  // true
Object.hasOwn(getComputedStyle(document.body), 'z-index')  // true
```

However, *this* evaluates to false

```
Reflect.ownKeys(getComputedStyle(document.body)).includes('z-index')  // false
```

How is it possible for `Object.hasOwn(x, y)` to evaluate to true, yet `Reflect.ownKeys(x).includes(y)` to evaluate to false? This does't make any sense.

Note also that the fact that getComputedStyle(document.body) is a read-only and computed CSSStyleDeclaration object is not why this is happening. The CSSStyleDeclaration object retrieved from the style property of an HTMLElement is not read-only, but the same thing happens:

```
Object.hasOwn(document.body.style, 'z-index') // true
Reflect.ownKeys(document.body.style).includes('z-index') // false
```

MDN says (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

> CSS property values may be accessed using the getPropertyValue(propName) API or by indexing directly into the object such as obj['z-index'] or obj.zIndex.

I understand the *convenience* of allowing accessing the value by `obj['z-index']`. What I want to know is how the resulting divergence in truth-value between Object.hasOwn(x,y) and Reflect.ownKeys(x).includes(y) is even possible given the rules of the Ecmascript language.

Edit: I found another stackoverflow question that asks the very same thing ([how does it work element.style["background-color"]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66654977/how-does-it-work-element-stylebackground-color)) but it received no definitive answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already analyzed the situation correctly.

However, there is nothing that would disallow this, and you can create such a situation yourself too, using a Proxy. For example:

```js
function createCaseInsensitiveObject() {
  return new Proxy({}, {
    getOwnPropertyDescriptor (target, property) {
      return Reflect.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, property.toLowerCase())
    },

    defineProperty (target, property, descriptor) {
      return Reflect.defineProperty(target, property.toLowerCase(), descriptor)
    },

    has (target, property) {
      return Reflect.has(target, property.toLowerCase())
    },

    get (target, property) {
      return Reflect.get(target, property.toLowerCase())
    },

    set (target, property, value) {
      return Reflect.set(target, property.toLowerCase(), value)
    },

    deleteProperty (target, property) {
      return Reflect.deleteProperty(target, property.toLowerCase())
    }

    // Note: ownKeys is NOT overridden as it
    // would be impractical to return all permutations
    // of casing like hElLo etc.
  })
}

const obj = createCaseInsensitiveObject()
obj.Hello = 123
console.log(obj.HELLO) // 123
console.log(obj.hElLo) // 123
console.log('hElLo' in obj) // true
console.log(Reflect.ownKeys(obj)) // ['hello']
console.log(Reflect.ownKeys(obj).includes('hElLo')) // false
```

This explains the discrepancy: the `[[Has]]` internal method returns `true` and the `[[GetOwnProperty]]` internal method returns a valid descriptor, but the `[[OwnPropertyKeys]]` internal method returns an array that does not contain that key.

The `[[OwnPropertyKeys]]` internal function isn't meant to be used in such a way that you take the returned array and check whether it contains some key that you already know. It's meant to be iterated over in order to discover keys. Meaning: In reality, you would call `Object.hasOwn` to check for existence for some specific property, and use `Object.keys` (or, to include non-enumerable properties, `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`) just for iterating over properties. And in that case, you'd have the `CSSStyleDeclaration` behave nicely (every real property returned only once, but both ways of writing a property accepted when directly accessing a property whose name you already know).